# Define key when saving an object containing a list as field in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I save a Pojo containing an arraylist of another Pojo as field at Firebase with setValue(instance), then these list generates integer indices like 0, 1, 2, 3.. as keys. Is there a way to customize these keys? Say, the Pojo object of the list is a User object with an user id, and I would like to have that user id as key of the list entries instead of the integer values

```
class Group{
    ArrayList<User> users;
}

databaseReference.setValue(mygroupwithusers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a Map.  Copy the values from the ArrayList into a HashMap with the key of the map being the name of the property you'd like to use for each User object.  Then pass that Map to setValue().

Comment: of course.. replaced the arraylist by a hashmap, now I have what I need